# unable to login with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying learn how to log into websites with python requests, but based on what i've researched online, i'm not sure why I am still getting `status_code: 500` errors.

This is my edited Code:

```
client = requests.session()
url = "https://www.shareinvestor.com/user/do_login.html?use_https=1"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
a = soup.findAll('meta')
csrf_token = a[-1]['content']

login_data = dict(sic_login_header_username='foo', sic_login_header_password='barr', authenticity_token=csrf_token)
r = client.post(url, data=login_data)

print(r.status_code)
```

Any advice on what I am doing wrong is appreciated!

Comment: Could you double check that url? A 500 error is coming from the server you're trying to access, and as far as I can see that url is not valid. Possibly try- `https://www.shareinvestor.com/user/login.html`

Comment: @etemple1 Thanks for reverting. I did try that previously, but there was this dude who told me to use this url instead (the url that is currently in the code above). He has since deleted his answer.... when i try using `https://www.shareinvestor.com/user/login.html`, it gives me a `status_code: 404` error. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?